# Zshell PATH variable extra paths

Tags: macos, shell, path, zsh

I am pretty new to the Mac environment so I have lots of gaps knowledge-wise. I need to edit the order of the PATH variables that my system uses. I have a .zshrc file in my home directory which has the following contents as of now:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mehmetsanisoglu/Desktop/Programs/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mehmetsanisoglu/.rbenv/shims"
```

that's all, just these two lines. But when I type `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/mehmetsanisoglu/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/mehmetsanisoglu/Desktop/Programs/flutter/bin:/Users/mehmetsanisoglu/.rbenv/shims
```

I am guessing the .zshrc file I have crated appends the items I have in there to the actual list of PATH elements. My question is, how do I get there and edit the ordering of these elements, because I need the ".rbenv" to come before "/usr/bin". Thanks

Comment: ? Why not just `export PATH="/Users/mehmetsanisoglu/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"` then

Comment: Well, your `flutter/bin` and `shims` **is** in your PATH, so I don't understand your problem. Of course defining the PATH like this is not the best approach, but for sure it does work. What are you missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` has a special array variable `path` that's linked to `PATH` - changing one changes the other. Treating the path as an array of directories is often much handier than treating it as a string of colon-separated directories.

You can append to it with

```bash
path+=(/some/path)
# or
path+=(/some/path/1 some/path/2)
```

and prepend to it with

```bash
path[1,0]=/some/path
# or
path[1,0]=(/some/path/1 /some/path2)
```